# How to cleanly update Doctrine Collections in Symfony while both creating and removing elements?

Tags: doctrine, symfony6, doctrine-collection

I'm having an issue with Doctrine Collections (using Symfony 6.2.9 and doctrine/orm 2.14.2) .

---

**The objective :**

I am parsing a config file from a firewall, and creating elements into my database (the firewall entity + policies + interfaces). On the first parse, all objects are created, no problem.
When I do a second parse (few days later generally), objects like policies may have been altered (modified, or removed), or not.

**The model is :**

- Firewall can have oneToMany Policies
- Firewall can have oneToMany Interfaces
- Many-ToMany relationship between Policies and Interfaces (a policy is linked to on or more interface, and vice-versa)

So, for my parsing, I'm trying to do a refresh of my firewall and its objects (eg policies and interfaces). I want to add new elements, update existing one (that part is ok), but also (and that's where I struggle), remove obsolete elements.

**What i tried :**

I tried brut force and removing all Policies and Interfaces (I mean only the one associated to the firewall, not all my database of course), but then Doctrine always generates new element, and thus new IDs in database, which I find kinda messy.

When I don't clean everything, I managed to retrieve existing Policies / Interfaces and update them, ... But, in that case, if a policy has been deleted in the configuration, it still show in my database / I can't find a way to delete it.

---

Is there a **clean** way to update my Collections ?
Do I need to persist informations to the dabatase at some point, or refresh the entities ?

Answer (score 0):

For information, I managed the issue.
Steps are :

- I assign NULL to the relating entities firewall value that I'm going to update / delete (kind of a detach)
- I update the existing values if they exist and re-assign the firewall ID
- And persist everything
  At the end, in order to clean the databse, everything that has "null" as firewall is removed.